# Parameters for application load balancer gets added to gateway load balancer in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

While creating gateway load balancer using terraform, we are using below code:

```
resource "aws_lb" "gateway_lb" {
  name                       = GWLB01
  load_balancer_type         = "gateway"
  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = true
  enable_deletion_protection = true
  subnets = [subnet-xxxxx, subnet-yyyy]

}
```

The terraform plan shows below :
[image]

The below parameters are for application load balancer still gets added here, is there any way to remove these?

```
drop_invalid_header_fields = false
enable_http2 = true
enable_waf_fail_open = false
idle_timeout = 60
```

Comment: No, these are probably not required when creating the LB but are added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Those are default required values. If you don't provide them terraform will add them for you.

If you don't like the "provided default value" you can change it to another.

Example

```
drop_invalid_header_fields = false
```

Just set it to "true" in your code

```
drop_invalid_header_fields = true
```

You can't "eliminate" them.